# Angular validation - Get error: Property Required, and Parser Error

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to do validations for email and password in Angular with the following code but I am running into errors.

```
<input type="text" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userService.selectedUser.email" name="email" placeholder="Email"
  required [pattern]="emailRegex"  [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' :signUpForm.submitted && !email.valid }">
  <div *ngIf="signUpForm.submitted && email.errors">
    <label *ngIf="email.errors.required" class="validation-message">This field is required.</label>
    <label *ngIf="email.errors.pattern" class="validation-message">Invalid email address.</label>
  </div>
  <input type="password" #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="userService.selectedUser.password" name="password" placeholder="Password"
  minlength="4" required [ngClass]="{'invalid-textbox' :signUpForm.submitted && !password.valid }">
  <div *ngIf="signUpForm.submitted && password.errors">
    <label *ngIf="password.errors.required" class="validation-message">This field is required.</label>
    <label *ngIf="password.errors.minlength" class="validation-message">Enter atleast 4 characters.</label>
  </div>
```

Error:

> Property 'required' comes from an index signature, so it must be
> accessed with ['required'].

When changed to `*ngIf="email.errors.['required']"` it gives the error:

> Parser Error: Expected identifier for property access at the end of
> the expression [email.errors.['required']]
> finally when changed to `*ngIf="[email.errors.['required']]"` it gives the error:
> Parser Error: Expected identifier for property access at the end of
> the expression [[email.errors.['required']]]

What am I doing wrong with the validation?

Comment: Change to `*ngIf="email.errors?.['required']"` ?

Comment: Add it to the answer so i can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
*ngIf="email.errors?.['required']"
```

**Reference:**

[Validating input in template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-template-driven-forms)