# Angular Validation Error: Parse error required and min length

Tags: angular, validation

I have this question on a form that needs to be validated, which I'm trying to do below:

```
      <div class="question">
      <div class="row">
        <h5>1. Requestors Name (Your name or JHED ID)</h5><p class="required">*</p>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="requestorName" name="requestorName" required minlength="2"
             [(ngModel)]="model.requestorName" #requestorName="ngModel"/>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="requestorName.invalid && (requestorName.dirty || requestorName.touched)"
         class="alert">

      <div *ngIf="requestorName.errors?.['required']">
        Requester name is required.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="requestorName.errors?.['minlength']">
        Requester name must be at least 2 characters long.
      </div>

    </div>
```

I made this using the examples here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

However, when I try to load the page I get this error:

```
NG5002: Parser Error: Expected identifier for property access at the end of the expression [requesterName.errors?.['minlength']]
```

If I remove the min length div I still get the same exact error but for expression `[requesterName.errors?.['required']]`

What am I missing or what have I done wrong here? There are a lot of similar questions on this, but they all have solutions that say something like "use `*ngIf="email.errors?.['required']"`" as in this question: [Angular validation error: Property Required, and Parser Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264334/angular-validation-error-property-required-and-parser-error) but I'm already doing that.

What is different in mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `requesterName?.errors?.required`

Comment: Ok I did both ````requesterName?.errors?.required```` and ````requesterName?.errors?.minlength```` and this solved the issue. Why is this? Why does the example not do it like this and why should I?

Comment: Because when you use `requesterName.errors?.['required']` the use of `[]` throws an error if the key does not exist rather than ignoring it. But when you use `requesterName?.errors?.required` it does not throw an error and results in a false when used with `*ngIf`. Hope this explanation was useful

Answer (score 1):

You're using two different variables:

**requesterName** and **requestorName**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="requestorName" name="requestorName" required minlength="2"
         [(ngModel)]="model.requestorName" #requesterName="ngModel"/>
```

Comment: I updated the question and made them all ````requestorName```` but this did not affect the issue.

Comment: @ColePerry Did you also update the the model.requesterName in your .component.ts file?

Comment: No because that is unnecessary. Check the answer I accepted, that was correct and the problem has been resolved.